# Function to determine font color of data driven page attribute in ArcMap 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, arcgis-10.2, font

ArcGIS 10.2

I am looking for an IF/ELSE statement that I can place in the text properties of my Data Driven Page Attribute item to change the font color based on the value in that field.  Here is the function I have been trying.  Its a variation on a function for basic map label.  I can't get this function to work w/ dynamic text.

`Function FindLabel<dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="RP_Slope" domainlookup="true"/> > 2 then
    FindLabel = <CLR red='255'><dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="RP_Slope" domainlookup="true"/></CLR>
else
    FindLabel = <dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="RP_Slope" domainlookup="true"/>
end if
End Function`

Comment: <dyn type="page" property="RP_Slope"/> is the code for the dynamic name pointing at the slope field.  I need to add to this code so when the value is outside the allowed limit the value will appear in red.

Comment: I'm not sure how much clearer I can make my question.  Can you please remove the hold?

Answer (score 1):

In the Answer to the Question [Doing Math calculations within ArcMap Dynamic Text?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35540/how-to-do-math-within-arcmap-dynamic-text) I folund.

> This from Jeffrey Barrette, an ESRI employee:
>
> "No. Dynamic Text provides many different formatting options for
>   dates, times, coord systems, etc but it does not provide the logic to
>   perform mathematical operations. You would need to incorporate Python
>   and then use arcpy.mapping to update text elements in a layout."

In the same way the if/then logic that you are seeking to use within a Dynamic Text element to determine font colour simply does not exist.